# Sending variables from one view to another view and url in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

What I want is when I click an image, it redirects to a URL (another view) which is made by the `something/image_name`. I am making the project in vue.js. I am thinking of doing this by using props (passing all the variables needed from the first view to the next view). But the data is not displayed in the 2nd view. Also, I want to know how can I make the URL like `something/image_name`. I am using it by hardcoding the URL.

**routes.js**

```js
const router = new Router({
    mode: "foo",
    base: "foobar",
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/event/:title",
            name: "event",
            component: event,
            props: true,
        }
```

where `title` is the variable (`event.title` to be more precise) I want to pass from other view. I also want to get `title` in URL also.

**view 1**

```html
<template>
    <div src="image_location" :to="/event/{{event.title}}"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "event",
    components: {
        Event
    },
    data: function initData() {
        return {
            event: {},
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

**view 2** (Event.vue) (its URL should be foobar/event/{{ title }})

```js
props: {
        event: Object,
    }
```

I tried router-link also but lack of its documentation restricts me from using it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an @click event to the image and programmatically move the user to the new URL when they click on the image. Something like:

```
  <imge src="..." @click="$router.push(`/event/${event.title}`)" />
```

Comment: I guess this will only open the required  URL when the user is on the current page. I want to open the link even if the user puts the link in the link bar.